# SNMP Trap receipt and processing on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, snmp

Without installing any extra software or monitoring applications, can I configure Windows Server 2003 to receive SMNP Traps from our UPS and, based on the message, perform actions (send shutdown commands to non-key servers, initiate scripts, etc).

I've got the SNMP Service and the SNMP Trap Service running on the server. Port 123 is not listening (I've got to figure out if that is a GP security policy pushed from higher-up IT (is that supposed to be TCP or UDP?)). The Community Name is set. And our APC Symmetra system is ready for me to tell it where to send the SNMP Traps.

Using already on the system tools (small executables and plugins are usually OK depending on where they come from), is this possible?

Comment: The SNMP Trap service should be listening on port 162, not port 123 (which is NTP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need additional software.

The SNMP trap receiver in the "SNMP Trap Service" in Windows Server 2003 can receive traps from other machines but can only forward them to another destination. It's less of a "trap receiver" and more of a "trap proxy".

Comment: There is a built in trap receiver if you install the optional SNMP component, there's just no built in application to act on those traps.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I dropped on an edit to make this answer more accurate.

Comment: Ok, this is a bit more subjective, but what tools do you prefer or use for SNMP Trap handling? I see many network monitors offer Trap Handling, and there are other utilities, but do you have preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Solar Winds "Kiwi Syslog" product Free version.  There is also a commercial version.
Details and downloads from:
http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-syslog-server-overview/

Collects SNMP traps in addition to Syslog type messages.

Easy to set up.  You can configure alerts etc.

Comment: That's great, but the OP specifies "without extra software", however. There isn't built-in trap handling in W2K3.

Comment: Right, there is no trap handling software in 2k3 server.  But Music2myear commented on your response asking  for additional input.